# GeckoFX\Awesomium Многопоточность

Tags: c#, многопоточность, awesomium, appdomain

Добрый день!

Задача такая: Приложение которое будет запускать много несвязанных между собой ВебБраузеров, а они в свою очередь должны выполнять работу. Несвязанность нужна т.к. будут использованы разные Прокси, Кукки и т.д.

Я рассматривал: WebBrowser, GeckoWebBrowser, Awesomium(WebControl, WebView), CefSharp;

WebBrowser и cefSharp нет возможности запуcтить несколько экземпляров с разными прокси, их сразу откидываем.

Из всего что есть под C#, подходит GeckoFX и Awesomium в плане прокси, то что нужно. Но вот с ними проблема, сразу много экземпляров запустить не получается. Пробовал с многопоточностью поиграться, без результатов. Awesomium вообще ругается что из другого потока обращаюсь. А Gecko бесконечно висит, и подписаться на события, или ждать когда загрузится страница бес толку((

Прошу помощи, как быть. Или может вообще другие инструменты посоветуете.

Есть еще мысль использовать AppDomain(.Net remoting), запускать браузеры в разных доменах. Что скажите по этому поводу?

HttpWebRequest - не предлагать т.к. в работе браузера может встретится страница с ajax.  Да и вообще нужно имитировать работу человека.

```
[MTAThread]
    private void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
            GeckoWebBrowser browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
            browser.Navigate("https://yandex.ru");
            while (browser.Document == null || browser.Document.ReadyState != "complete") {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }));
        t.Start();            
    }
```

Этот не возможно дождаться

А это один из вариантов Awesomium

```
Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView wc = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768);

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {

            wc.Source = new Uri("https://yandex.ru");
            while (wc.IsLoading)
            {
                WebCore.Update();
            }

        }));

        t.Start();
    }
```

Вот что пишет: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Comment: А вы не обращайтесь из другого потока, вот и не будет ошибки. Покажите ваш код, без него сложно сказать, где именно у вас проблема.

Comment: Так если обращаться  не из другого потока, а из основного UI не откликается.

Comment: Давайте код, без него непонятно :)

Comment: Не, Application.DoEvents и Thread.Sleep не выглядит обнадеживающе.

Comment: Вы должны создать отдельный UI-поток (STA, не MTA), запустить в нём цикл сообщений, и в нём уже держать ваш GeckoWebBrowser. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2076166

Comment: Кроме того, вы, кажется, неправильно создаёте GeckoWebBrowser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3371655

Comment: Ок, сейчас попробую

Comment: С GeckoFX  ничего не вышло, создать GeckoWebBrowser получается только в том потоке в котором инициализировали xullrunner, если пробовать в разных потоках то просто создается один GeckoWebBrowser, а в остальных потоках не создаются, хотя на инициализацию Xullrunner не ругается, пробовал инициализировать с разных папок разные потоки, но все равно не получается. Сейчас буду пробовать с Awesomium.

Comment: А если инициализировать в каждом потоке? Ну и вы ж делаете это в UI-потоках, правильно? (STA и цикл сообщений.)

Comment: В каждом не получается, получается в любом хоть UI хоть не UI но только в одном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была ваша проблема. Я пробовал chromium, но там не получилось задать отдельные прокси, да и раздельные куки тоже не всегда работали. А вот с awesomium все работает.
Чтоб вызывать и создавать WebView из разных потоков вам нужно использовать Invoke.

```
wv.Invoke(new Action(() =>
  {
      wv.Source = "http://google.com".ToUri();
  }), new object[] { });
```

Суть в том, что обращения к браузерам должны всегда происходить из потока, где был инициализирован WebCore. В моем wpf приложении это главный поток. Сделать в фоновом не получилось.
Я написал немного инфраструктурного кода, который помогает работать с браузером из любых потоков без проблем. Еще там предусмотрена возможность синхронной загрузки страниц. На гихаб пока не могу выложить.

Comment: По этому методу действительно все работает, и еще пробовал в BackgroundWorker тоже работает.